# Google Drive API: Change ownership on file not working (only writer/reader works)

Tags: java, file-permissions, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to changing a file to another user an make the new user the owner of an file , but this does not work.

I first of did a Permissions insert and added the newuser as writer, that was no problem. But I didn't work by adding the user as "owner" directly (Internal 500 error was returned)

Then I tried to use the Permission: list and saw the newuser as writer. Got that id of user and tried to use Permisson Update, and use the "transferOwnership" to the newuser.
But that don't work either, I always get the 500 Internal Server error.

Could this be anything that the newuser does not belong to the same email-domain that I as the owner belongs to?
If that is the reason, is there any other why to change the ownership to an external domain?

```
Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZRkl82BYjpu
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
"role": "owner",
"type": "user",
"value": "newuser@officedomain.com"
}
```

This gives an error:

```
500 Internal Server Error

- Show headers -

{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "internalError",
"message": "Internal Error"
}
],
"code": 500,
"message": "Internal Error"
}
}
```

Edit:
Have found it possible to change ownership when both user have the same email-domain. But now to another issue.
When the ownership is moved to another used, the file is not shown in "shared files" sounds correct to me, but it is not shown in the directory structure either.
It is visible if I choose "show all files" and possible to search for if I specify the file name. But shouldn't it also be in the "My drive" at root ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not able to add `owner` permission for user from another domain. You can only add `owner` permission for users, from the same domain to which current file owner belongs to.

I think we can solve it using below algorithm:

- Add `writer` permission to source file for user from destination-domain.com. [Permissions: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert). (Request to source-domain.com)
- Now you can copy this file. [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy). (Request to destination-domain.com).
- Copy permissions, comments and any other properties which you want.

I know, this is not the easiest solution but it works.

Comment: If I understand you correct, by sharing the file to the newuser and then the newuser copies the file to his own Drive, he will be the owner of the file?
The problem is that this should be more or less automated and this then requires to be logged in to other accounts as well.

Comment: Exactly, newuser will be the owner of the copied file. You can authorize request using OAuth2 (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2). See also this page: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.ch/2011/12/calendar-api-v3-2-legged-oauth-java.html - it shows how to configure 2-legged OAuth2 for Calendar API. Drive API looks similar.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. But that will not work in this case since this is an automated tool where the Users are not involved until afterwards when the file is already moved. And the server cannot authenticate towards all users.

I created 2 demo users with the same domain, and was possible to send over the "ownership" to the new user. And then removed the permission of the old user (old owner). But when login to the new user the file aren't found anywhere. But it is possible to search for the file and then it came up. Sounds like a bug in Google Drive.

Comment: This algorithm can be automated also. I've implemented it. I am able to move files between users from different domain.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, so I perform request on behalf of another user that is not authorized the automated tool but as they are in the same domain it will work as I understand it, yes?

The only thing I cant find is to enable "Two-legged OAuth access control" in Google Console. Or was this only for OAuth v1.0

Also I found out this link:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/oauth2-dev/Qqu8sgbGHyM
that sets ".setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)". I will try that as well.

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: great workaround, and works fine so long as you have both oauth tokens. thanks!

Comment: It worked in that sence, that the file was moved to the other user, but when changing the owner (on the same domain) the file also ended up in root folder. After a while I changed over to use domain-wide solution for the most parts and only give users write-access that wasn't in the same domain.